# How to speed up Min of DateObjects?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, date-and-time, dataset

I'm in version 10.0.1 using a `Dataset` to do some plots and things.  For one of the plots I need to get the minimum date of a some filtered set of the `Dataset`. I can get this set of `DateObjects` without any issues and add the `Min` operator in the `Dataset`.  However, `Min` in the `Dataset` does not return if the list gets *too big*.

I worked out that it is the `Min` function that is the issue.

This returns immediately.

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2000, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2000, 10, 1}], "Month"] // Min
```

However, add more dates and it never returns.

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2000, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2014, 10, 1}], "Month"] // Min
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here? I don't know how many records will return before I apply the filter on the `Dataset`. Nor do I know what the minimum of the filtered set will be.

Is there perhaps a workaround using a `Dataset`?  If it is a bug, how do I report it?

Thanks,

Edmund

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `AbsoluteTime` :-

```
DateObject[Min[Map[AbsoluteTime,
   DateRange[DateObject[{2000, 1, 1}],
    DateObject[{2014, 10, 1}], "Month"]]]]
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried it with `Normal /* Min /* DateObject@testDateMin[All, "Date", AbsoluteTime]` and it returns immediately.  I wonder why they are not converting with `AbsoluteTime` in `Min` for ``_DateObjectQ`. Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @Chris 10.3.1 on my computer, when evaluated on `DateObject[{10, 12, 1}], DateObject[{2014, 10, 1}]` - note starts w year ten, so ~20k objects -  your workaround doens't seem faster than wrapping in `//Dataset//Min`. In fact, `//Length` takes almost as long, prelim timing studies.

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes, something seems to have been improved.  The OP's version works fast now.

Answer (score 4):

Consider also 'Sort' and 'First'

```
>  (your expression here...) // Sort // First
```

`Max` also suffers poor performance on `DateObject`s that can remedied in similar form:

```
> (your expression here...)  //Sort // Last
```

To comment on the OP situation: at this time (MMA 10.0.2) **short lists also suffer unacceptable delays**. For example, applying `Min` or `Max` to a list of 16 elements takes 17 seconds in my system, whereas the `First @ Sort` (or `Sort // First`) forms take about 3 milliseconds.