# Finding the positions DateList dates in a range in large data set

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

There are similar questions to this like [list search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-find-the-position-of-elements-in-a-list-satisfying-criteria) but this question is focused on finding at subset of dates in `DateList` format within a range of specified dates from the original key list.  The actual list of events is large at ~300,000 x 60 table covering 18 months of activities.  The dates are indexed but this maybe not the best approach for find the subset items.  I have generated a sample set of the same format using

```
sampledata = Table[DateString[DatePlus[DateList[][[1 ;; 3]],
  RandomInteger[547]], {"Month",",", "Day", ",", "Year"}], {i, 2000}];
```

I am attempting to use the keys from position index to

```
dates = PositionIndex[ DateList[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year"}}][[1 ;; 3]] & /@ sampledata]
```

but the search method may be too slow to embed in a `Manipulate` loop with the date limits dynamically selected from the keys to display the other data associated with the dates.

```
upperlimit = {2015, 1, 30};
lowerlimit = {2015, 1, 15};

datekeys = Flatten[Position[(DateDifference[#, upperlimit ] > Quantity[0, "Days"] 
&& DateDifference[#, lowerlimit] < Quantity[0, "Days"]) & /@ dates, True]]

selecteddates = Sort[Flatten[dateindex[dates[[#]]] & /@ datekeys]]
```

Gives the index of the original data list

```
sampledata[[selecteddates]]
```

I chose this method to generate the date index outside of the `Manipulate` call since the other functions are fast.  Any suggestions on how to speed up the process?

Comment: Could store a copy of the dates in AbsoluteTime and use Between to select the dates in a given range?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64137

Comment: have you considered `DatePattern`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working with `DateObject`s instead of strings from `DateString`.

```
sampleDates = 
  DateObject[(FromDigits /@ StringSplit[#, ","])[[{3, 1, 2}]]] & /@ sampledata;

{upperlimit, lowerlimit} = 
  DateObject/@ {{2017, 1, 30}, {2017, 1, 1}};
```

With everything as `DateObject`s the matching does not need to translate from a string into a date for every comparison. Now operators like `Between` can be used directly.

```
selecteddates = 
  Flatten[Position[sampleDates, #] & /@ 
    Select[sampleDates, Between[{lowerlimit, upperlimit}]]];

sampledata[[selecteddates]]
```

If you want to view dates in that particular format then use the `DataFormat` option of `DateObject`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried `Parallelize@Select` to try and speed it up but it doesn't help as it does not parallel select.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting Edmund's answer to `Dataset` - given `sampleDates`:

```
ds = Dataset[sampleDates][
 Select[Between[DateObject@{{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 30}}]]]
```

Then, can easily post process, eg, makeshift calendar:

```
ds[GroupBy[DateValue[#, "Week"] &] /* KeySort, Sort]
```

[image]

Who knows why Jan 1 is in week 52.